# Is there Getting Started RAILS documentation for someone only interested in developing REST APIs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rest

Our team will be using Rails for the development of RESTful APIs only. We will use Ember or Angular for our GUI layer and will sometimes just publish our APIs for external consumption. For someone such as myself who doesn't know Rails at all yet, and doesn't really want to learn the View part, finding good "getting started" documentation hasn't been very successful. I've found a few articles on how to build REST APIs, but even these articles seems to assume prior Rails knowledge. Can anyone point me to docs for a Rails newcomer who only wants to build REST APIs? Thanks!

Comment: This is not an appropriate question for SO. Flagged to close

Comment: I don't agree at all. I am asking for a pointer to specific information. Why do you think it's not an appropriate question?

Comment: This is why: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic -- Specifically, #4 on the list: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: Fair enough. If those are the rules, those are the rules. I guess the problem is that, to get help, the rails website refers you to stackoverflow and stackoverflow isn't an appropriate forum for all the kinds of help that a person might need.

Answer (score 0):

Check out: https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api

This is a starting point for a version of Rails better suited for JS-heavy apps.

Rails API provides: trimmed down controllers and set of generators, specifically built for API type applications.

Comment: Thanks for the reference but I wouldn't call that "getting started" documentation at all. I think it assumes a lot of prior Rails exposure. What is really needed is something as basic as the existing Rails getting started documentation.

Comment: Check out those: https://thesocietea.org/2015/02/building-a-json-api-with-rails-part-1-getting-started/ and https://wyeworks.com/blog/2015/6/11/how-to-build-a-rails-5-api-only-and-backbone-application